# How to write a Delete Method for a Menu program

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm stuck on how to write a delete method for a menu (object orientation) program I am writing. The menu gives the user the option to delete the last name entered on the program. I'm completely stuck on this part! Would be greatly appreciated if you guys/gals could show me a simple delete method!
Many Thanks!

This is my code so far for Adding a Name:

```
public static int addOne(String theArray[], int location, String theName, int noofvalues)
{
    int step;

    if(noofvalues == 0)
        {
            theArray[0] = theName;
            noofvalues++;
        }
    else
        {
            for(step = noofvalues - 1; step >= location; step--)
                {
                    theArray[step + 1] = theArray[step];
                }
            theArray[location] = theName;
            noofvalues++;
        }
    return noofvalues;
}
```

Comment: show some code that you have right now please..

Comment: `public void delete(){ lastName = ""; }`

Comment: So your real problem is about how to remove an element from an array, right?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes! I just dont know to write it

Comment: I recommend to use List instead of arrays. Or even maybe stack

Comment: @bartektartanus I havent used stack before ? I was gonna put a listAll method in but I wanted to get the delete one out of the way first!

Comment: @bartektartanus this looks like homework, so I guess `List` usage would be innapropiate.

Comment: Then @ConorDoyle21 should add `homework` tag to this question :)

Comment: @bartektartanus seems like you haven't been here for a while: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/182862)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - it was a joke. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like homework, I won't provide any code **at all** (otherwise, I would solve the homework and you won't learn anything), only ideas an possibly an algorithm to do it.

- Store the last name inserted by the user in a variable. Let's say, this variable is `lastInsertedName`.
- Go through all the elements in your array and search this `String` in it. When you find `lastInsertedName` in the array, store the index in a variable, let's say `indexFound` and stop the loop.
- If `indexFound` is greater or equals than 0:

  - Move all the elements starting at `indexFound` in the array one position back.
  - Decrease the variable that acts as the size of your array.

Comment: Today I've used all of my votes, but I will come back tomorrow and +1 your post! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use List:

```
public static int addOne(List names, int location, String theName, int noofvalues)
{
    names.add(location, theName);
    return names.size();
}

public static void deleteOne(List names, int location){
    names.remove(location);
}
```